# Lua sorting tables

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I know nothing about Lua, but I was able to modify a script I wanted to. I'm having troubles sorting a table though.

I've found table utils (convert table to string), 
here's my table:

```
{{line="(Golden Aura) Challenging An owl would be either very brave or very stupid.",range="(+16 to +21)",message="(Golden Aura) Challenging An owl would be either very brave or very stupid.",colour="crimson",srt=9,keyword="owl",name="An owl"},
{line="(Golden Aura) A busy squirrel chuckles at the thought of you fighting him.",range="(+3 to +8)",message="(Golden Aura) A busy squirrel chuckles at the thought of you fighting him.",colour="gold",srt=7,keyword="squirrel",name="(Golden Aura) A busy squirrel"},
{line="(Red Aura) A parakeet should be a fair fight!",range="(-2 to +2)",message="(Red Aura) A parakeet should be a fair fight!",colour="springgreen",srt=5,keyword="parakeet",name="(Red Aura) A parakeet"},
{line="(Golden Aura) Challenging A cat would be either very brave or very stupid.",range="(+16 to +21)",message="(Golden Aura) Challenging A cat would be either very brave or very stupid.",colour="crimson",srt=9,keyword="cat",name="A cat"}}
```

I was able to add srt key and I want to sort a table by that. Can someone kind tell me how to do that, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table.sort( table:t [, function( left, right ):sorting function ] )
```

So, since you want to sort by `v.srt`, you would do something like:

```
table.sort( t, function( a, b ) return a.srt < b.srt end )

for k, v in pairs( t ) do
  print( v.srt, v.name )
end
```

Which should sort them in ascending order and then display them.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what I was doing wrong, I used a[srt] and b[srt]:)

Comment: @user2618401 You might have been thinking `a["srt"]` which is the same as `a.srt`.